# Python - Find what character is in a given position inside a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi and thank you for stopping by this question, let me explain my problem.

Basically, i have a number, let's say it's **13**.

Now, i have this:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

I need to know what's at position 13, basically a reverse alphabet.index()

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
item = alphabet[12]
```

Note since Python is zero-indexed, we use the 12th index to find the element in position 13.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `[]` operator like this:

```
alphabet[12]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
print(alphabet[12])
```